# Windows Service needs to know if currently on windows login screen after system bootup

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-services, boot

I have a scenario wherein after a system boots up and reaches the Windows Login screen, then a background service (which would be running good till that time) needs to know if user is currently on the Login screen i.e to determine if he is not yet logged into the system.

How can this be achieved in C#?

BTW, I know that there are System events like SessionEnding but they will not serve my case which is right at the point on login screen, after bootup.

Comment: Try WTSEnumerateSessions.

Comment: Any example? Also I need solution in C# only